# Write to a unique attribute of a non unique div

Tags: jquery

folks!

I have two variables:

```
var day =  $(this).text();
var day_id =   $(this).data('num');
```

I have HTML inputs with unique ID:

```
<input class="update_day" data-id="88" type="text" value="5" name="day">
<input class="update_day" data-id="89 type="text" value="5" name="day">
<input class="update_day" data-id="90" type="text" value="5" name="day">
```

etc...

I need to update a SPECIFIC input (stored in variable "day_id") with certain data (stored in "day")

It is supposed to look like this:

```
$(".update_day WHERE data-id= day_id).val(day);
```

Thank you in advance! Sorry for the newbee question. I have honestly been trying to solve it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(".update_day[data-id='90']").val(day);
```

---

if value is stored in variable `day_id`

```
$(".update_day[data-id='" + day_id + "']").val(day);
```

[Attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: Damn. I still ahve not enough reputation to vote up! Mate, thanks a million - good one!!! I'll be back with my vote , I do promise =)

Comment: Done, Lord Tushar!!! Thanks once again. works fine. damn... spent so much time and the ansewr was so dman simple. hehe... gotta study JQ properly